# How to call the function in node js

Tags: node.js

I have return the function in mysql.js as :

```
function myFunction(resourceIdentifiers,callback){

    dbconnection.execute( function(err,response) {

        response.query('call SP_ExposePricingDetailforUI(' 
                                      + resourceIdentifiers + ')'
                      ,function (err, rows, fields) {
                          console.log(rows);
                      });
                 }
        );
        return rows;            
}
```

And tried to call it at another script file restservice.js as :

```
mysql.myFunction(resourceIdentifiers , function(err,rows) {
    console.log(rows);
}
```

But I get error as the function myFunction is Undefined.

Comment: Are you exporting myFunction?  i.e.: module.exports.myFunction = myFunction;

Comment: actually i need the result to be sent to api call as response from restservice.js and not from mysql.js. kindly suggest me a solution

Answer (score 1):

If `mysql.myFunction` is `undefined`, then you're probably not actually exporting it:

```
function myFunction(resourceIdentifiers, callback){
    // ...
}

exports.myFunction = myFunction;
```

Function and variable declarations are "*private*" to the module by default. Only those members you explicitly export will be accessible from other modules.

---

You also won't be able to use `return rows;` as you're trying to. Asynchronous code is event driven and doesn't *wait*, which `return` would need it to do.

`myFunction` already has a `callback` argument and you're passing a `function` for the value. You just need to call it:

```
// ...
function (err, rows, fields) {
    callback(err, rows);
}
// ...
```

---

You should also at least [escape `resourceIdentifiers`](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values) when concatenating.

But, generally better is to use a placeholder (`?`) and the optional, 2nd argument to `.query()`:

```
response.query(
    'call SP_ExposePricingDetailforUI(?)',
    [ resourceIdentifiers ],
    function (err, rows, fields) {
        callback(err, rows);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to callback within the result of response.query.  Something like this.

mysql.js:

```
function myFunction(resourceIdentifiers,callback){

    dbconnection.execute( function(err,response) {

        response.query('call SP_ExposePricingDetailforUI(' 
                                      + resourceIdentifiers + ')'
                      ,function (err, rows, fields) {
                          callback(err, { rows: rows, fields: fields});
                      });
                 }
        );
}

module.exports.myFunction = myFunction;
```

restservice.js:

```
mysql.myFunction(resourceIdentifiers , function(err,resp) {
    console.log(resp.rows);
}
```

Update - removed the return rows statement that I missed the first time around.

Comment: thanks dc5. but when i run above script , i get rows is not defined

Comment: Try console.log(rows) from within your response.query callback.  What is logged there?

Comment: @Prem - I'd inadvertently left the return rows statement in the code. Does that get rid of your rows not defined error?