# How to resolve the error 'not defined' in node js

Tags: node.js

i wrote a script which throws error as 'rows is not defined' but it seems to be correct :

```
function myFunction(resourceIdentifiers,callback) {

    dbconnection.execute( function(err,response) {

        response.query('call SP_ExposePricingDetailforUI(' + resourceIdentifiers + ')',
            function (err, rows, fields) {
                callback(err, { rows: rows, fields: fields});
            }
        );
    } );

    return rows;
}

module.exports.myFunction = myFunction;
```

Comment: Why are you returning rows at the end of the outer function?  It won't be available in that scope, but your callback approach is the right way around the async problem...

Comment: Likely because I accidentally carried it over in an answer to [his original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797805/how-to-call-the-function-in-node-js) (that answer has now been fixed)

Answer (score 2):

After I formatted your code to make it readable, I see that the line `return rows` exists outside your callback function, where `rows` is not in scope. You need to define `rows` directly within `myFunction` and then assign to it from within your sproc callback function.